# Tailwind Custom Color varables not working

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a unique problem.
bg-[--2nd-card-color] works but not bg-2nd-card-color,
Few days back  bg-2nd-card-color was working
Globals.css file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m79CP.png)

Tailwind config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oGD2.png)

I have tried everything

Comment: I see it worked as normal. Is the CSS file content look like this `@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
:root {
  --1st-card-color: red;
  --2nd-card-color: green;
}`